Moments of two probability distributions match. Can the distributions have support differing by an interval?
Let me define the support of a probability distribution $f$ as the set of all locations $x$ where $f(x)>0$. I'll denote it $S(f)$. Suppose the distributions $f$ and $g$ have matching moments. Can the symmetric difference between $S(f)$ and $S(g)$ contain an interval?

Here is my motivation. There's a famous example that distributions whose moments match need not be identical. This example gives a whole family of distributions, but they all have the same support (up to a point). I'm wondering whether having matching moments forces (nearly) matching supports, even if having matching moments doesn't force the values of the distributions to otherwise match.

The other direction is easy.  Moments are defined as integrals over the distribution.  Changing the value of a function at one point cannot change the integral.  As the integrals are countably additive, you can change the function at any countable collection of points without changing any moments.
